# Should $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{n}, b + \frac{1}{n})$ be $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am confused about the limiting behavior of as $n \to \infty$, $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty (a-\frac{1}{n}, b + \frac{1}{n})$.

I have read that it is the case that this set becomes closed, but I can't help but to think that if we take $n \to \infty$, then $\dfrac{1}{n} \to 0$, and the inner set is $(a,b)$

Can someone please help?

Comment: Is there any set in the intersection that $a$ is *not* in?

Comment: Try a concrete example, say with $a=b=0$. Then what happens?

Comment: @T.Bongers Woof woof good way to think about it woof

Comment: @TedShifrin A point and it is open in the discrete topology

Comment: Don't muddle things with the discrete topology. The issue is that an infinite intersection of open sets need not be open (nor need it be closed).

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows The most important thing is that topology has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You say you're concerned about the limiting behavior. You talk about the set "becoming" closed, and about letting $n\to\infty$. All of that shows you're thinking about this totally wrong.

It's important to realize here that the notation $$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$has nothing to do with limits! It means that $A$ is the intersection of all the sets $A_n$.  Not the limit of the intersection of the first $N$, it's the intersection of all of them, period.

Like in calculus an infinite sum is not really the sum of infinitely many numbers, because we can't add infinitely many numbers - an infinite sum is really the limit of finite sums? Understanding that is a good thing, but that's leading you astray here. This is not like that at all - that intersection *is* the intersection of infinitely many sets.

What the notation does mean is that $x\in A$ if and only if $x\in A_n$ for every $n$.

So go back to your problem. You should be able to convince yourself that given $x$, you have $x\in(a-1/n,b+1/n)$ for every $n$ if and only if $x\in[a,b]$. And there you  are.

Comment: Isn't $\lim_n\cap_{k=0}^n A_n$ defined to be $\cap_k^\infty A_k$ generally?

Comment: I've never seen $\lim_n\cap_{k=0}^n A_n$ in any context.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Sometimes, yes. Which I take as evidence that I'm spot on saying the intersection (or of course the _meaning of_ the intersection) has nothing to do with limits. If in fact that limit is defined to be the intersection, then if we think that the intersection is defined as a limit we're in trouble. That limit being defined as the intersection just shows that the intersection is the more fundamental concept.